# Extracting matrices from other matrices in R

Tags: r

I have the following matrices

```
input1 <- matrix(rnorm(600), nrow=200, ncol=3)
input2 <- matrix(rnorm(150), nrow=3, ncol=50)
```

Each of the 5 columns of `input1` correspond to the 5 rows of `input1`.  From this I want to extract three matrices, `output1`, `output2` and `output3` in which:

```
dim(output1)
[1] 200   50
dim(output2)
[1] 200   50
dim(output3)
[1] 200   50
```

where first each value in column 1 of `input1` is multiplied by row 1 of `input2` to give `output1`. And next each value in column 2 of `m1` is multiplied by row 2 of `m2` to give `output2`. Similarly to get `output3`. What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the most efficient, but is this what you mean?

```
output1 <- matrix(0, nrow = dim(input1)[1], ncol = dim(input2)[2])

for(i in 1:dim(input2)[2]){
    output1[,i] <- input1[,1]*input2[1,i]
}
```

(and similarly for `output2` and `output3`)

Comment: that's it although I guess some sort of vectorization makes it faster

Answer (score 0):

It's ordinary vector outer product:

```
output1 <- input1[,1, drop = FALSE] %*% input2[1,, drop = FALSE]
output2 <- input1[,2, drop = FALSE] %*% input2[2,, drop = FALSE]
output3 <- input1[,3, drop = FALSE] %*% input2[3,, drop = FALSE]
```

You need `drop = FALSE` so matrices don't coerce to vector.